# Using the same ID value multiple times to anchor to the same location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a horizontal grid consisting of 3 image squares - The action that I am trying to produce is when any grid section is clicked, the user will be anchored down to a slideshow box that is being displayed below the grid.  the first bit of HTML that I have pasted below is one grid (there will be 3) - and the section section of HTML is the slideshow section.  Since I cant use the same ID tag multiple times in HTML, I believe I will need to use some for of Javascript or jQuery to take the user from the grid on click to the .  Could anyone help me figure out how to do that?

```
<div id="grid-item" class="grid-item grid-item-1">
    <div class="grid-project">
        <img class="profile-image" src="img/image1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-overlay">
        <div class="project-info">
            <a href="#project-link" id="toggle">
                <h4 class="project-name">Headline 1</h4>
                <p class="project-categories">description 1</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="grid-item" class="grid-item grid-item-2">
    <div class="grid-project">
        <img class="profile-image" src="img/image.png">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-overlay">
        <div class="project-info">
            <a href="#project-link" id="toggle">
                <h4 class="project-name">Headline 2</h4>
                <p class="project-categories">description 2</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


 <div id="slideshow" class="slideshow">
        <div class="slideshow_inner">
        <a name="project-link" class="anchor">
            <img src="img/slide_img_1.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So the code you've pasted works? You're having trouble with code you didn't include?

Comment: @MichaelCoker i just updated the html.  So the first use of the anchor tag #project-link works in grid-item-1 but its not linking in the grid below that (grid-item-2)

Comment: Seems to link to me... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmOLob

Comment: The _id_ should be unique in the same document.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `id=""` you can't use same id twice... Each element should have different id name. Change this in the second grid:

`<a href="#project-link" id="toggle">`

to this:

`<a href="#project-link" id="toggle2">`

and don't use same id twice...

Also, you have used `name=""` in the second section of your html, instead of `id`:

`<a name="project-link" class="anchor">`

Comment: I apologize, I should have deleted the id of toggle since this isnt current being used and doesnt have any action associated with it.  So since I cant use the same ID to anchor to a specific section using HTML, I assume I would need to implement some use of javascript then in order to get the value of an element clicked and then navigate to X section

Comment: If you want to use different links in different places to link to one id - then it is not a problem. Just create an element, like this: 

`<div id="my-anchor"></div>`

and then you can use however many links to link to this id. for example:

`<a href="#my-anchor">Click Here</a>` - you can use it however many times you want. You just can't give same id to more than one element, but it doesn't matter in your case.